# what does "working life organization" mean?

Tags: meaning

> The polytechnic develops and provides learning and working environments, which enable the experiments and study of new activities and procedures together with the companies and other
>   working life organisations.

what does working life organisations mean?

I know meaning of *working life* is the period of time in your life that you work.

Answer (score 2):

Working life organisations are organisations one deals with during their working life. These can be (commercial) companies that employ people, but also other employers like governmental organisations or charity organisations that act as employers. But there are also organisations that play a role in people's working life that are not employers (to those individuals), such as a chamber of commerce.

I am interpreting the expression on the spot, the whole sentence seems to have been constructed with the aim to be as vague as possible while maintaining a a modicum of sense. This is a style that is commonly found in mission statements, motivational texts and (commercial) propaganda. In this case, I would factually rewrite the sentence to something like:

> The school uses classes and labs to teach the students about the real world.

But I'm afraid said polytechnic would not feel that sentence would be flowery enough to adequately promote their sophisticated curriculum and methods.

Comment: In this case, I'd say the polytechnic was trying to maintain a modicum of sense, but failed. I like your rephrasing, though.